# In this figure find AC=x

Tags: triangles

[image]

Can you find $AC$, when only the angle $DBC$ and $DEB$ are $90$ grades. 
*I can't because I think they **should** give the angle $CAB=90$ grades too.*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Without $CAB$ being right, you can have $BC$ be a range of lengths, which means triangles $ABC$ and $DEB$ need not be similar.